# Can "name" of package.json be Chinese?

Tags: node.js, npm

If I named "name" in the npm file "package.json" in Chinese, like : {"name":"哈哈"}, is it valid?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) it should be valid. But it's probably not recommended. Especially the following point is likely to give headaches or incompatibilities:

> - The name ends up being part of a URL, an argument on the command line, and a folder name. Therefore, the name can't contain any non-URL-safe characters.